# How to access variable with dot

Tags: php, var-dump

Here is part of my `var_dump($GLOBALS['pagination']);`:

```
object(VmPagination)[376]
  ...
  public 'pages.total' => float 4
  public 'pages.current' => float 1
  public 'pages.start' => int 1
  public 'pages.stop' => float 4
  ...
```

Is there any ideas how can I access `pages.total` and other three variables with dot? I tried `$GLOBALS['pagination']->pages.current`, but it's doesn't work.

Comment: `echo $GLOBALS['pagination']->{'pages.current'};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `{}` notation:

```
$foo->{'bar.baz'} = 'qux';
```

e.g:

```
php > $x = new StdClass();
php > $x->{'foo.bar'} = 'baz';
php > var_dump($x);
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["foo.bar"]=>
  string(3) "baz"
}
php > echo $x->foo.bar;
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$foo in php shell code on line 1
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant bar - assumed 'bar' in php shell code on line 1
bar
php > echo $x->{'foo.bar'};
baz
```